# Copying libraries with soft links to Remote Linux Device with Qt Creator

Tags: linux, qt, embedded, qt-creator, embedded-linux

I'm experimenting with some open source code and I'm having trouble deploying it to a remote linux device.  The error happens when uploading the library's soft links.  I have the following:

- Ubuntu 10.04 running in VMWare Player on a Windows 7 machine
- An embedded linux device
- Qt Creator 2.4.1

I've used the same system with other Qt projects and have been able to deploy to the remote linux target.  This project is different in that it uses a library with soft links.  Right now I have the following in my *.pro file:

```
# remote deployment of libraries
install_lib.path = /home/name
install_lib.files = ../../lib/*
install_lib.extra = cp ../../lib/* /home/name

# install
target.path = /home/name
sources.path = /home/name
INSTALLS += target sources install_lib
```

The error I receive is the following:

```
ln: invalid option -- 'v'
BusyBox v1.19.4 (2012-09-11 06:53:36 PDT) multi-call binary.

Usage: ln [OPTIONS] TARGET... LINK|DIR

Create a link LINK or DIR/TARGET to the specified TARGET(s)

    -s  Make symlinks instead of hardlinks
    -f  Remove existing destinations
    -n  Don't dereference symlinks - treat like normal file
    -b  Make a backup of the target (if exists) before link operation
    -S suf  Use suffix instead of ~ when making backup files

12:39:46: Failed to upload file '/home/name/Qt/proj/lib/libq.so'.
12:39:46: Deploy step failed.
```

To my untrained eye, it looks like Qt is trying to use a command that is not supported by BusyBox on my device.  Is there a better way to move the files from my development environment to the device?  Chances are I won't need to change anything in the library, but I'd like the automatic upload if I do.

By the way, I also tried using QMAKE_PRE_LINK and QMAKE_POST_LINK without success.  Same story with trying to add a Deploy Step in Qt Creator.  If there's another way to link my project with the library, I'd be willing to try that too.

**Update**

Here are portions of the Makefile to show what qmake is producing based on my *.pro file.

```
INSTALL_PROGRAM = install -m 755 -p

install_install_lib: first FORCE
    @$(CHK_DIR_EXISTS) $(INSTALL_ROOT)/home/name/ || $(MKDIR) $(INSTALL_ROOT)/home/name/ 
    cp ../../lib/* /home/name
    -$(INSTALL_PROGRAM) (edit)/lib/libqhttpserver.so $(INSTALL_ROOT)/home/name/
    -$(INSTALL_PROGRAM) (edit)/lib/libqhttpserver.so.0 $(INSTALL_ROOT)/home/name/
    -$(INSTALL_PROGRAM) (edit)/lib/libqhttpserver.so.0.1 $(INSTALL_ROOT)/home/name/
    -$(INSTALL_PROGRAM) (edit)/lib/libqhttpserver.so.0.1.0 $(INSTALL_ROOT)/home/name/
```

Honestly, it doesn't seem like the install_lib.extra field is doing much.

Comment: BusyBox has only very simple versions of utilities. So BusyBox's ln has no -v option. Probably you can workaround the problem by removing -v options from generated Makefile manually. However, you would need to alter qmake configurations, to make it produce proper Makefile.

Comment: I don't see '-v' or 'ln' in the Makefile.  I'll update my question with what I do have.

Comment: It could help to see the command resulted in ln/busybox's error message. Don't you have any ln occurrences in Makefile?

Comment: The only mention of ln is in the line "SYMLINK = ln -f -s".  That is also the only time SYMLINK is mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Creator deploys the files itself without using the Makefile, so editing those will not help.

There was a lot of work wrt. making Creator work better with remote linux since version 2.4, so you should try getting a newer version.